# C#: Class does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, function, delegates

I am currently trying to search through an array of objects via a name, and wants the output to be the index of the array. However, an error occurred when I tried to call my searching function (Does not contain a definition). I have no idea how to solve this problem.

I am very new to programming so pardon me if I'm doing everything wrong, and please keep things as simple as possible.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Initialize array based on number of records
        RecordArray.Init(5);

        //Calling FindByName
        RecordArray.FindByName (RecordArray.rArray, "Name3");
    }
}

public class RecordClass
{
    //Declaring member variables
    public string Name;
    public int Number;
    public string Email;
}

public class RecordArray
{
    public static void Init(int Size)
    {
        //RNG for phone numbers
        Random Rnd = new Random();

        //Creating an array of RecordClass
        RecordClass[] rArray = new RecordClass[Size];

        //Loop through the array
        for(int i = 0; i < rArray.Length; i++)
        {
            rArray[i].Name = "Name" + i;
            rArray[i].Number = Rnd.Next();
            rArray[i].Email = rArray[i].Name + "@gmail.com";
        }
    }

    public static int FindByName(RecordClass[] rArray, string Name)
    {
        //Loop through rArray to find if Name matches. If match, return index. Otherwise, return -1.
        for(int i = 0; i < rArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rArray[i].Name == Name)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Line 9 of the pasted code here, at 

RecordArray.FindByName (RecordArray.rArray, "Name3");

The error occurs under rArray, and it says: 

'RecordArray' does not contain a definition for 'rArray'

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error message says it is. You haven't declared a member named `rArray` in the class. Please read the error messages more carefully. You may be surprised at just how informative they can be, once you get past treating every single error as having the same "compiler won't compile your code" meaning.

Answer (score 0):

rarray is only declared in a function so you wont have access to it.  you could try something like this

```
public static RecordClass[] Init(int Size)
{
    //RNG for phone numbers
    Random Rnd = new Random();

    //Creating an array of RecordClass
    RecordClass[] rArray = new RecordClass[Size];

    //Loop through the array
    for(int i = 0; i < rArray.Length; i++)
    {
        RecordClass record = new RecordClass();
        record.Name = "Name" + i;
        record.Number = Rnd.Next();
        record.Email = record.Name + "@gmail.com";
        rArray[I] = record;
    }

    return rArray;
}




static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Initialize array based on number of records

    //Calling FindByName
    RecordArray.FindByName (RecordArray.Init(5), "Name3");
}
```

Comment: The error vanishes, but when I ran the program, it crashed.

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I edited where you create the records so it creates an instance of the RecordClass before you try and assign it values in init

Answer (score 0):

First, let me start by saying that there is almost never a need to write your own array.
The C# langange and .NET framework support arrays and many other collection types, so it's really not needed.

Having said that, here is what's wrong with your current code:
The class `RecordArray` does not contain a member called `rArray`.
For your code to work, you must break up this line in the init function:

```
//Creating an array of RecordClass
RecordClass[] rArray = new RecordClass[Size];
```

into two separate code lines. First, you must create a static member for `rArray`, second, you initialize it in the `Init` method:

```
public class RecordArray
{
    public static RecordClass[] rArray {get; private set;}

    public static void Init(int Size)
    {
        //RNG for phone numbers
        Random Rnd = new Random();

        //Creating an array of RecordClass
        rArray = new RecordClass[Size];

        //Loop through the array
        for(int i = 0; i < rArray.Length; i++)
        {
            rArray[i] = new RecordClass();
            rArray[i].Name = "Name" + i;
            rArray[i].Number = Rnd.Next();
            rArray[i].Email = rArray[i].Name + "@gmail.com";
        }
    }

    public static int FindByName(RecordClass[] rArray, string Name)
    {
        //Loop through rArray to find if Name matches. If match, return index. Otherwise, return -1.
        for(int i = 0; i < rArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rArray[i].Name == Name)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is gone now, but I am having a crash.

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: My code was missing a row: `rArray[i] = new RecordClass();`. Now fixed.

Comment: [I'm not...](http://rextester.com/OUXZH69620). You must be doing something I'm not doing...

Comment: omg apparently i didn't remove a line i was testing... got it now!

thanks so much!

Comment: hm, I tried creating an object under RecordClass, and then referring to it under the array. It appears to look the same as your code, but now it isn't working... 

Rextester link: http://rextester.com/IZGH51550

Comment: You can't access `objRecord` using the class name because it isn't static. I recommend reading a good c# book or tutorial. Using trial and error to learn a programming language is not the way to go.

Comment: Alright. I'm actually going through a C# tutorial and doing my own practice... just that this problem came along. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)